# Remove double scrollbar on block extension

Tags: css, django, django-views, scrollbar

I have a quite simple project structrue where I have packed a plotly-dash app on django using the django-plotly-dash package. I have done several tests and I have set everything working propertly, however when the dash app is inserted a double scrollbar appears. This is a resume of my code:

**base.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Dash App</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    {% block content %}

    {% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

**dashboard.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load plotly_dash %}

{% block content %}
    <div class="{% plotly_class name='dash-app' %}" style="height: 100%; width: 100%;">
        {% plotly_app name="dash-app" ratio=1 %}
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mSHVU.png) you can see the double scrollbar I mentioned.

Any idea how can I remove one so that the inserted app uses the same as the browser page?

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the scrollbar in css.

```
.dash-app::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}
```

You many need to use other browser prefixes to get it work.

Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::-webkit-scrollbar

Comment: That did not make the trick for me, I tested it on several browsers :(

Comment: what browser are you using that the screenshot is taken in?

Comment: Firefox, but I also tested it on Chrome which is supposed to be full compatible with the css property

Comment: Try `overflow-y: hidden;` on the div. that will hide the scrollbar.